# How to make an executable shell script to run my .py program and input a file

Tags: python, bash, shell, terminal, stdin

I have a python program that takes a file as input from std input, runs some calculations on the data, and outputs results to std output. Here is the code I am using for getting the input file:

```
import math
import sys

name = sys.argv[-1]
inf = open(name, 'r') 
outf = open("test.txt", 'w')

col1, col2, col3 = [], [], []
for row in inf:
    a, b, c = row.split('\t')
    col1.append(a)
    col2.append(b)
    col3.append(c)
```

I need to create a shell script to execute the program and provide the input file. Ideally the shell script should work so that it can be used as follows:

```
$ cat inputfile.txt | scriptname
```

and/or

```
$ ./scriptname < inputfile
```

I have tried a couple of different basic shell scripts but haven't had any luck in getting this to work. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to make this script and/or how to modify my python code to make this work. Thanks!

If it helps, I beleive I am using python 2.7.3 on mac osx 10.8

P.S. This is actually my first experience programming (i started learning python just for this project) so please excuse the crappy code.

Comment: Why not execute your python script directly from the commandline with `> python yourpythonprogram.py inputfile.txt`?

Comment: thanks. that works fine for me, but this is for a school assignment and the professor would like to test my program by running the above commands on an executable shell script. Don't worry, its not a programming class so I'm not cheating :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a 'shebang' to the script, use chmod to make it executable and it runs without being wrapped in anything else. Your code opens files from the command line, which is not stdin or stdout, so that's gotta change. And since you don't write anything, I just made something up!

But it should be something like:

scriptname:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math
import sys

col1, col2, col3 = [], [], []
for row in sys.stdin:
    a, b, c = row.split('\t')
    col1.append(a)
    col2.append(b)
    col3.append(c)
sys.stdout.write('something should be written\n')
```

And in the shell...

```
$ chmod u+x scriptname
$ cat inputfile.txt | ./scriptname
something should be written
$ ./scriptname < inputfile.txt
something should be written
```

Comment: "Assuming this is linux" isn't a very good assumption when the question says "I believe I am using… mac osx 10.8". But this is all true for _any_ modern POSIX-like system, so you can just remove the first three words and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the script like this:

```
./shellscript.sh inputfile.txt
```

Inside your shellscript.sh:

```
python scriptname.py $1
```

Make sure that the python script and input file are in the same path as the shell script or modify the script to reflect where the python script is located `/path/to/script/scriptname.py`

Comment: Sorry, but this is really messy. Just make the python script executable and ditch the extra shell script.

Comment: Sure I agree with you, but we don't know why he is doing it that way so this answers his question.

Answer (score 0):

Firs, your code isn't reading from stdin; it's reading from a file at the path specified by the last argument. This means there is no way a shell script could possibly feed it input.*

You want to change your code so it either always reads from stdin, or reads from stdin if not given a filename, or reads from stdin if given `-` as a filename. For example:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    name = sys.argv[-1]
    inf = open(name, 'r')
except:
    inf = sys.stdin
```

---

On top of that, your script isn't runnable. On Windows, you need to name it with a `.py` extension. But on almost any other platform, you need to `chmod +x scriptname` the file to make it runnable, and add a shebang line at the top of the script to tell the computer which interpreter to use to run it (because otherwise it'll guess `/bin/sh` or something else useless). In particular, on any modern POSIX-like system, including OS X and linux, you do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

---

Having fixed both of those problems, you can now do exactly what you wanted:

```
$ ./scriptname < inputfile
```

… which will do the same thing as:

```
$ ./scriptname inputfile
```

However, you might want to consider using the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module, which magically takes care of most of this for you:

```
import fileinput
inf = fileinput.input()
```

---

* Well, you could save the input into a tempfile and then feed it that path. But that's cheating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to handle both - i.e. be able to pass files and be able to treat stdin as the very same file object internally - you should look into StringIO / cStringIO:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html